# Nginx rewrite to remove first (generic) path node

Tags: proxy, regex, nginx

I am currently writing a dispatcher that will dispatch different URLs to specific service URLS.

I essentially want to dispatch something like:

```
POST http://nginx/awesome_service/a/lot/of/params/and?so=on
```

to

```
POST http://awesome_service/a/lot/of/params/and?so=on
```

I already achieved by hard coding the service name:

```
location /awesome_service {
    rewrite ^/awesome_service(/.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://awesome_service;
}
```

However I have different services with different names and I don't want to duplicate the routes.

I used a map to from name to url:

```
map $uri $service_url {
  ~^/awesome_service/ "http://awesome_service";
  ~^/mediocre_service/ "http://mediocre_service";
}
```

So it's easy to dispatch to a variable proxy url:

```
location /awesome_service {
    rewrite ^/awesome_service(/.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass $service_url;
}
```

However, I'm still struggling with the rewriting.

This is what I came up with so far:

```
location ~ ^/([^\/]+)/.* {
    set $service $1;
    rewrite ^/$service(/.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass $service_url;
}
```

The request is captured and passed on. But the rewriting fails. The service still sees the first part of the url.

Is there maybe a mixup with the regex or am I passing in the variable wrong?

Comment: Do you have tens or hundreds of applications? If not it's better stick with several explicit location blocks.

Answer (score 1):

The `rewrite` in your `location` block gets evaluated first, then `proxy_pass` is used. This is the reason your `map` block won't work with `$uri`. Because when the `map` block is triggered the URL is already rewritten.
I have this config in my lab which works as expected:

```
map $custom_service $custom_backend {
        google "https://www.google.com";
        bing "https://www.bing.com";
}
location ~ ^/([^\/]+)/.* {
        set $custom_service $1;
        rewrite ^/[^\/]+(/.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass $custom_backend;
}
```

The `map` block goes into the `http` block and the `location` block into the `server` block.

Your URLs look like this:

```
http://nginx/google/some/params -> backend is now -> https://www.google.com/some/params
http://nginx/bing/some/params -> backend is now -> https://www.bing.com/some/params
```